# How to apply a filter on multiple objects using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-framework

I have the user object defined as below.

```
$scope.users = [{id: 1, name: 'Adam', friends: [{name: 'John', age: 21, sex: 'M'}, {name: 'Brad', age: 32, sex: 'M'}]}]
```

Then I have the following code:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users>
 <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
 <div ng-repeat="friend in user.friends | filter:searchText">
  {{user.name}} {{friend.name}} {{friend.age}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Now when I type in the textbox the text: 'searchText', I want the filter to display the name of the user and the name/age of the friend. Can anyone help me with how to do this?

If I am correct, then I think that I need to create a custom filter for this or is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because you want to filter on two things at once -- some properties of the friends array and also the user -- you'll need to create your own [custom filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.templates.filters.creating_filters) that accepts 2 additional parameters:

```
myApp.filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(friends, searchText, username) {
    var searchRegx = new RegExp(searchText, "i");
    if ((searchText == undefined) || (username.search(searchRegx) != -1)) {
        return friends;
    }
    var result = [];
    for(i = 0; i < friends.length; i++) {
        if (friends[i].name.search(searchRegx) != -1 || 
            friends[i].age.toString().search(searchText) != -1) {
            result.push(friends[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
  }
});
```

Then call it like so:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
   <input type="text" ng-model="searchText">
   <div ng-repeat="friend in user.friends | myFilter:searchText:user.name">
      {{user.name}} {{friend.name}} {{friend.age}}
    </div>
</div>
```

":searchText:user.name" is the way you pass additional arguments to a custom filter.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/mwrLc/).

Comment: Thanks Very much Mark! But this filterFilter(friends, searchText) will filter on all objects of friends i.e, name, age and sex or else only name and age. My requirement is i want only 'name' and 'age' to be searchable and results to be filtered only on these two objects of friends, as those are the fields getting displayed and not on 'sex'

Comment: I realize how old this is... but what might be happening when my input's 'searchText' is always undefined inside of the filter? Scoping issues, obviously, but why?

Comment: @Clever, I suggest you create a new question that includes your HTML and the filter.

Comment: This was super helpful for me, thank you! Only caveat I would add that I missed at first glance was that when you specify the filter in the ng-repeat parameters, make sure you replace the usual "filter:" with the name of your filter (aka "myFilter:<param1><param2>"). Also, not 100% sure what you're doing in the first line of your return function, checking for the letter "i" in the searchText. I didn't need that in my solution, so I took it out.

Comment: @shaunpickford, "i" is a [RegExp flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) that means "ignore case".

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users>
 <input type="text" ng-model="search.$">
 <div ng-repeat="friend in user.friends | filter:search">
  {{user.name}} {{friend.name}} {{friend.age}}
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks fastreload! This helps! But what are the object this will filter for? Will this filter only on **user's name** and **friend's name and age**?

Comment: As described in the documentation, it would search for all properties of an objects inside an array of objects. You can think of `$` as a magic wildcard.

Comment: Thanks fastreload! Here in my friend object I have three attributes: name, age and sex. But i don't want the sex to be searchable. Is there a way i can achieve this?

Comment: You need to create a function that takes an element in the array and result true/false depending on your needs, and pass the function name as `filter`s parameter.

"function: A predicate function can be used to write arbitrary filters. The function is called for each element of array. The final result is an array of those elements that the predicate returned true for."