# ng-repeat :filter by single field

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I have an array of products that I'm repeating over using ng-repeat and am using

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:by_colour">
```

to filter these products by colour. The filter is working but if the product name / description etc contains the colour then the product remains after the filter is applied.

How do I set the filter to only apply to the colour field of my array rather than every field?

Comment: Custom filters are also powerful =), you might like it, example: http://noypi-linux.blogspot.com/2014/07/angularjs-filter-creating-custom-filter.html

Comment: Different solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24992197/257470

Answer (score 490, accepted):

See the example on the [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) page.  Use an object, and set the color in the color property:

```html
Search by color: <input type="text" ng-model="search.color">
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search">
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, are there any benefits to doing it this way rather than the method suggested below?

Comment: @Seglespaan, not really.  You might find that the method presented by bmleite and blesh read nicer, since you can see that you are filtering by color.  This method is more compact, which might be useful if you want to search by multiple properties, and you'd rather not have a long object in the HTML:  `filter:{ color: '...', size: '...', ...}`

Comment: @MarkRajcok, how would I be able to search by multiple properties, looking at the union, rather than intersection?

Comment: @jetcom, you'll need a custom filter, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/13845135/215945

Comment: I don't know if the OP was asking how to make a search box as much as how to filter out values in an ng-repeat when they're repeating on page. The answer beneath this one seems most relevant to the question asked.

Answer (score 591):

Specify the property (i.e. `colour`) where you want the filter to be applied:

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{ colour: by_colour }">
```

Comment: what if i want ! by_colour as filter:{ colour: ! by_colour }"

Comment: @rjdmello just prepend `'!'+`, like this `<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{ colour: '!'+by_colour }">`

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly, but the first thing that came to my mind was: `<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{ resultsMap.annie: '!!' }">` **or** (something equivalent) like this: `<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:by">` and on the controller: `$scope.by = { 'resultsMap.annie': '!!' };`. This second approach gives you more control over the property being filtered. Note: `'!!'` means "not null".

Comment: How could i do this dynamically? for example something like `<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:customFilter">` where `customFilter = '{ colour: by_colour }'` and then that customFilter would be able to change dynamically.

Comment: @Federico, the `customFilter` can be a simple object on your `scope` that you update whenever needed. Check this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uP6tDh7wnGSSNYlkOyL5?p=preview).

Comment: Yeah, found that out a bit after posting. I was trying to do it inline with the html something like `<span ng-init="by={ resultsMap.annie: '!!' }"` and ng-clicks to change it. But it wouldn't work. I guess it was reading it as a string instead of JSON object. Doing it in the controller worked perfect.

Comment: How can I use this type of filter for 2 or more colors. Like if my array got 10 types of color I need to filter red and green at the same time using a check box.. Is there any way to do so.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  It is the most succinct.  Well, except that 'colour' has too many vowels.

Comment: I had to put single quotes around my filter field e.g. <div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{ 'colour': by_colour }">

Answer (score 177):

You can filter by an object with a property matching the objects you have to filter on it:

```js
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.products = [
       { id: 1, name: 'test', color: 'red' },
       { id: 2, name: 'bob', color: 'blue' }
       /*... etc... */
   ];
});
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: 'red' }">
```

This can of course be passed in by variable, as Mark Rajcok suggested.

Comment: lets say that i have this kind of scope.products: { id: 1, name: 'test', color: 'lightblue' },
{ id: 2, name: 'bob', color: [{foreground : black, background:white}] }. then how can i filter product based on color:background to get white value?

Comment: @Gery: Honestly, I don't think you can. Either way, using filter: at all is sort of bad practice, IMO. In that it puts logic in your view that should really be in your controller, and isn't very testable.

Comment: This is a way to move the filtering to the controller and extend the model. http://www.ozkary.com/2015/05/angularjs-value-mapping-with-dynamic.html.

Answer (score 108):

If you want to filter on a grandchild (or deeper) of the given object, you can continue to build out your object hierarchy. For example, if you want to filter on 'thing.properties.title', you can do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: { properties: { title: title_filter } }">
```

You can also filter on multiple properties of an object just by adding them to your filter object:

```
<div ng-repeat="thing in things | filter: { properties: { title: title_filter, id: id_filter } }">
```

Comment: is this like 'or' type or 'and' type of filter.

Comment: Same question is that an AND or an OR when filtering more than one property?

Comment: for OR filter only way is custom filter, I think

Answer (score 107):

Best way to do this is to use a function:

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: myFilter">
```

**javascript**

```
$scope.myFilter = function (item) { 
    return item === 'red' || item === 'blue'; 
};
```

Alternatively, you can use ngHide or ngShow to dynamically show and hide elements based on a certain criteria.

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful when you have complex comparisons

Comment: Using `ng-hide` was perfect and exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 66):

Be careful with angular filter. If you want select specific value in field, you can't use filter.

Example:

**javascript**

```
app.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.products = [
       { id: 1, name: 'test', color: 'lightblue' },
       { id: 2, name: 'bob', color: 'blue' }
       /*... etc... */
   ];
});
```

**html**

```
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: 'blue' }">
```

This will select both, because use something like `substr`
 That means you want select product where "color" contains string "blue" and not where "color" is "blue".

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter: { color: 'blue' }:true">` will work on only exact matches (the 'true' at the end is the comparator argument: [link](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter)

Answer (score 24):

Search by color:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchinput">
<div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:{color:searchinput}">
```

you can do an inner nest too.

```
filter:{prop1:{innerprop1:searchinput}}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you were to do the following:

```
<li class="active-item" ng-repeat="item in mc.pageData.items | filter: { itemTypeId: 2, itemStatus: 1 } | orderBy : 'listIndex'"
                id="{{item.id}}">
    <span class="item-title">{{preference.itemTitle}}</span>
</li>
```

...you would not only get items of itemTypeId 2 and itemStatus 1, but you would also get items with itemType 20, 22, 202, 123 and itemStatus 10, 11, 101, 123.  This is because the filter: {...} syntax works like a string contains query.

However, if you were to add the *: true* condition, it would do filter by exact match:

```
<li class="active-item" ng-repeat="item in mc.pageData.items | filter: { itemTypeId: 2, itemStatus: 1 } : true | orderBy : 'listIndex'"
                id="{{item.id}}">
    <span class="item-title">{{preference.itemTitle}}</span>
</li>
```

Answer (score 7):

my way is this

```
subjcts is

[{"id":"1","title":"GFATM"},{"id":"2","title":"Court Case"},{"id":"3","title":"Renewal\/Validity"},{"id":"4","title":"Change of Details"},{"id":"5","title":"Student Query"},{"id":"6","title":"Complains"}]
```

> sub is a Input field or whatever you like

Displaying like this

```
<div ng-if="x.id === sub" ng-repeat=" x in subjcts">{{x.title}}</div>
```

Comment: In general using ng-if is a clean solution

Answer (score 4):

You must use
 `filter:{color_name:by_colour}` instead of

```
filter:by_colour
```

If you want to match with a single property of an object, then write that property instead of object, otherwise some other property will get match.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the property in filter, of object on which you want to apply filter:

```
//Suppose Object
var users = [{
  "firstname": "XYZ",
  "lastname": "ABC",
  "Address": "HOUSE NO-1, Example Street, Example Town"
},
{
  "firstname": "QWE",
  "lastname": "YUIKJH",
  "Address": "HOUSE NO-11, Example Street1, Example Town1"
}]
```

**But you want to apply filter only on firstname**

```
<input type = "text" ng-model = "first_name_model"/>
<div ng-repeat="user in users| filter:{ firstname: first_name_model}">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want filter for one field:

```
label>Any: <input ng-model="search.color"></label> <br>
<tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
```

If you want filter for all field:

```
 label>Any: <input ng-model="search.$"></label> <br>
 <tr ng-repeat="friendObj in friends | filter:search:strict">
```

and 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter good for you