# Filter's second parameter not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to understand "filter" filter in AngularJS. Understanding from the docs, it also takes second parameter. If passed as "true", it performs a strict comparison.

**The HTML**

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Array of objects (Search all properties)</legend>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchObject" />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="value in arrOfObjects | filter: searchObject: true">
            <span>{{value.firstName}}</span>
            <span> {{value.lastName}}</span>:
            <span><strong>{{value.email}}</strong></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

**THE JS**

```
$scope.arrOfObjects = [
    {
        firstName: "Anup",
        lastName: "Vasudeva",
        email: "anup.vasudeva@email.com"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Vijay",
        lastName: "Kumar",
        email: "vijay.kumar@email.com"
    },
    {
        firstName: "Virat",
        lastName: "Kohli",
        email: "virat.kohli@yahoo.com"
    }
];
```

What I am expecting, if I type "aNuP", it will try to make exact match with all the properties and would not be able to return anything. Hence I should be seeing an empty list.

Am I missing something.

Comment: It doesn't return anything for `aNuP`: http://plnkr.co/edit/F2lbGkgADxV8tK8pZ0Rs?p=preview What are you seeing? Which version of Angular are you using?

Comment: Works as expected here:  http://jsfiddle.net/C7vfp/

Comment: @KayakDave, Thanks a lot. Can you tell me what wrong did I do in my code?

Comment: I think you might find this question useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field

Comment: @musically_ut, Thanks for the answer. When I type "aNuP", it shows up in the list. I am using Angular-1.2.2.

Comment: Works in 1.2.2:  http://jsfiddle.net/C7vfp/1/  So what we can say is that your code, as posted, is correct which points us to something outside of this code.  Is there anything else (like a $watch) that could be affecting `searchObject`?

Comment: The standard filtering works like contains and ignorecase on all fields.  To be more specific you need to use define which field you want to use or create your own custom filter method.

Comment: I got it. Thanks @Emmaentaler for the pointer :)

Comment: @musically_ut: Would you be kind enough to post this as an answer, so that I can mark it?

Comment: @Emmentaler should add his explanatory comment and any of the examples as an answer.

Comment: I will post a complete answer. I will steal @musically_ut plunk. Give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a plunker that shows the following explanation: http://plnkr.co/edit/b1vuJV4RFNQSdpfaw0Pd?p=preview

Angular filtering on objects works by comparing the object's fields to see if they contain the filter criteria while ignoring case.  This gives a broad usage that can be narrowed by adding a second boolean parameter `true` to indicate that you want to drop the `contains` rule.

In your example:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Array of objects (Search all properties)</legend>

    <input type="text" ng-model="searchObject" />

    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="value in arrOfObjects | filter: searchObject: true">
            <span>{{value.firstName}}</span><span> {{value.lastName}}</span>: <span><strong>{{value.email}}</strong></span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</fieldset>
```

Typing `Vasudeva`, `Anup` or `anup.vasudeva@email.com` will each filter out all but the first record because of an exact match on a single field.  So an exact match on **any** field will result in the record being shown.

Removing the 'true':

```
<li ng-repeat="value in arrOfObjects | filter: searchObject">
```

Gives a much larger inclusion set because it looks for the expression in any field and ignores case so typing the letter `a` ,which appears in one or more fields all objects, lists all of the objects.

To filter on a single field in the object use this format:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in arrOfObjects | filter: {lastName :searchObject}">
```

and similarly you can add the second boolean parameter to get an exact match:

```
<li ng-repeat="value in arrOfObjects | filter: {lastName :searchObject}:true">
```

Finally you can create a custom filter by defining a function in your controller that returns true or false for a given match.

```
<li ng-repeat="value in arrOfObjects | filter: myEmailFilter">
```

And in your controller write the actual filter.

```
$scope.myEmailFilter = function(value) {
    console.log(value.email);
    if(value.email.indexOf("email.com")>=0) {
      console.log('true');
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('false');
      return false;
    }
  };
```

Comment: Thank you so much for such detailed explanation.