# AngularJs filter by typed column in searchform

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I have an angular list-table that uses ng-repeat. I also have a standard searchform that searches all columns.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in test | filter: criteria">

<input type="search" placeholder="Search" ng-model="criteria">
```

Is it possible to extend the functionality of the searchform so that I can specify the column-name followed by a colon and then the searchphrase to only search in that column? See example below

Searchterms:

```
"Description: my awesome description"
// This will search in the description-column for "my awesome description"

"my awesome description"
// This will search in all columns for "my awesome description"
```

So in some way look for that colon and if found change the filter in some way.

Comment: Create custom filters for that. Refere this <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849804/angularjs-filter-by-multiple-columns-with-ng-repeat">link</a>

Answer (score 0):

```
filter:{'description':criteria}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model='test.age'> Age<br>

<input type="text" ng-model='test.about'> about<br>
<hr>

<table class="table table-striped">
  <tr ng-repeat='item in appVm.users |filter:test'>
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.age}}</td>
  <td>{{item.about}}</td>

  </tr>
```

See it in action [in this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZTv3tHimywEQZLpxA1Ee?p=preview)

Does that help enough?