# Filter multiple object properties together in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have an object in my controller

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.names = [{"Name":"Alfreds Futterkiste","City":"Berlin","Country":"Germany"}, 
{"Name":"Ana Trujillo Emparedados y helados","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"}, 
{"Name":"Antonio Moreno Taquería","City":"México D.F.","Country":"Mexico"},
 {"Name":"Around the Horn","City":"London","Country":"UK"}, 
{"Name":"B's Beverages","City":"London","Country":"UK"}];
});
```

I want to filter `Name`, `Country` at the same time.

```
Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name"> 
Country:<input type="text" ng-model="country"> <br>
 <table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter: name | filter: country">
   <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
   <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But both input boxes apply filter on both columns.

How to set the `name` input only to the first column and the `country` input, only to the second column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To filter on a specific property `foo`, you need to pass an object which has a property `foo` containing the string to match.

```
Name:<input type="text" ng-model="criteria.Name"> 
Country:<input type="text" ng-model="criteria.Country"> <br>

<table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter: criteria">
   <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
   <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've fixed the property names. It should work fine now. Properties usually start with a lowercase letter in JavaScript, hence my error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51083292/how-to-do-ng-repeat-with-filter-using-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

We can use any number of property like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (names | filter : {Name : name, 
                  City: city, 
                  Country: country })">
```

[See the demo on codepen](http://codepen.io/AliAdravi/pen/BpJqQJ?editors=1010)

Or we can use the object, but make sure when creating the object, ng-model property in object and property in result must match the name as well as the case and use the logic suggested by [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet)

Let's say I want to search on all the three property name, city and country then I will create the html like this

```
<div class='form-group'>
    <div class='row'>
       <div class="right-inner-addon col-md-4 ">        
        <input type="search" ng-model='model.Name' class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
       </div>
       <div class="right-inner-addon col-md-4 ">        
        <input type="search" ng-model='model.City' class="form-control" placeholder="City">
      </div>
       <div class="right-inner-addon col-md-4 ">        
        <input type="search" ng-model='model.Country' class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can use the filter like

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in filtered = (names | filter : model)">
```

[See the working demo here](http://codepen.io/AliAdravi/pen/BpJqQJ?editors=1010)

For other [filter tricks see](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1209/angularjs-filter-by-multiple-property-in-controller-ignore-case)

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer. All I have to do was to change the `html` part to this

```
Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name.Name"> 
Country:<input type="text" ng-model="country.Country"> <br>
 <table>
<tr ng-repeat="x in names | filter: name | filter: country">
   <td>{{ x.Name }}</td>
   <td>{{ x.Country }}</td>
</tr>
</table> 
</div>
```