# How to make $filter to search in multiple fields with OR in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I Have a data list say

```
$scope.data = [
{"id":34,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"NOTRELEASED","statusMessage":"Update Feedback","paymentMethod":"Cash"},
{"id":43,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"RELEASED","statusMessage":"Update Feedback","paymentMethod":"Cash"},
{"id":44,"buyername":"kdsingh1002","status":"RELEASED","statusMessage":"Update Feedback","paymentMethod":"Cash"},
{"id":50,"buyername":"kdsingh1002","status":"RELEASED","statusMessage":"Update Feedback","paymentMethod":"Cash"},
{"id":55,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"DISPUTE","statusMessage":"Dispute Raised","paymentMethod":"Cash"}
];
```

Now I applied a filter in HTML as:-

```
<input type="text" ng-model="querytx" ng-change="filterData()">
```

and defined filterData() in controller as:-

```
$scope.filterData = function() {
    $scope.finalData = $filter("filter")($scope.data, { id:$scope.querytx, buyername:$scope.querytx, status:$scope.querytx});
    };
```

Now what filterData returns in `$scope.finalData` is AND of `id, buyername` and status. iff `$scope.querytx` is there in `id, buyername and status,` then only that row is returned.

Where as **what I want is OR of id, buyername and status i.e if `$scope.querytx` is there in either of id, buyername and status, then that row should be returned.**

**Note:**

- I don't want to search in all fields.
- Can't perform something like this in HTML `<tr ng-repeat="item in data | myTableFilter:filterText:argumentTwo:argumentThree">` as shown
  in link https://stackoverflow.com/a/20850929/4948805 as I am using
  `$scope.finalData` in angular table which auto repeats.

Comment: The idea in the stackoverflow link you gave is to create a custom filter. And it's the good idea. You don't have to use a custom filter in a ngRepeat. This custom filter could be used as such :    $filter('filterTest')(myTableFilter, argumentTwo, argumentThree)

Comment: How to do something like that those rows should be returned where buyername==’kdsingh1002’ OR status=='NOTRELEASED’

And finally having result with 3 rows where:-

{"id":34,"buyername":"kamaldeep282","status":"NOTRELEASED","statusMessage":"Update Feedback","paymentMethod":"Cash"},
{"id":44,"buyername":"kdsingh1002","status":"RELEASED","statusMessage":"Update Feedback","paymentMethod":"Cash"},
{"id":50,"buyername":"kdsingh1002","status":"RELEASED","statusMessage":"Update Feedback","paymentMethod":"Cash"},


Note: I want to perform filter in controller.