# Filter in more than 1 column of a table in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter

I am trying to add a filter on more than one column of a table which is being populated by `ng-repeat` directive.

```
<tr ng-repeat="descriptiveField in vm.descriptiveFieldList|filter:{name:vm.searchText}" ng-class-even="'even-bgcolor'">                                             
  <td ng-bind=descriptiveField.name></td>
  <td ng-bind="descriptiveField.fieldDescription></td>
  <td style="text-align: left" ng-bind=descriptiveField.source></td>
</tr>
```

I have search box as

```
<input type="text"  ng-model="vm.searchText" class="search-input"/>
```

The filter is getting applied on Name only. I would to search on 2 columns name and source. How to do that?

Comment: You can use a custom filter for this. Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849804/filter-by-multiple-columns-with-ng-repeat

Comment: @RamDuttShukla what about accepting my answer?

Answer (score 3):

Use `$` to [filter any fields](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) (same level or deeper):

```
<tr ng-repeat="descriptiveField in vm.descriptiveFieldList | filter:search:strict}" ng-class-even="'even-bgcolor'">                                             
  <td ng-bind=descriptiveField.name></td>
  <td ng-bind="descriptiveField.fieldDescription></td>
  <td style="text-align: left" ng-bind=descriptiveField.source></td>
</tr>

<input type="text"  ng-model="search.$" class="search-input"/>
```