# angular js search by column

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, angularjs-filter

I have data like

```
{ column : [a,b,c], data : [["a",1,2],["b",4,5],["c",3,2]]}
```

table structure

```
<input type="text" ng-module="search">

<thead>
<tr>
  <th ng-repeat="n in column" ng-click="click($index)">n</th>  
</tr>
</thead>
<tr ng-repeat="i in data | filter:search">
  <td ng-repeat="j in i">i</td>
</tr>
```

how to make a search logic by columns?
I could search by any input but not by specific column

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849804/filter-by-multiple-columns-with-ng-repeat

Comment: May i know why you want that because you can search on whole table rather than seperate column..

Comment: @Parshuram, sometimes in little big data (crossing 1000's) with similar string in different column, its preferred to look into single column

Comment: @LonelyPlanet data are different, multiple array vs array of objects