# Is it possible to filter with multiple condition in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have an array of objects named result.data.EAPP_USERS

```
0:Object

SECURITYCLASS:90

USERID:"ASISH90"

1:Object

SECURITYCLASS:90

USERID:"VANDERSONIR"

2:Object

SECURITYCLASS:90

USERID:"BISWA90"

3:Object

SECURITYCLASS:93

USERID:"TABITHA93"


4:Object

SECURITYCLASS:93

USERID:"ASISH93"

5:Object

SECURITYCLASS:95

USERID:"TAB95"


6:Object

SECURITYCLASS:95

USERID:"ASISH95"
```

I want to filter data with SECURITYCLASS value 90 and 93.
I have tries this code

```
$scope.OpportunityOwners = $filter('filter')(result.data.EAPP_USERS, { SECURITYCLASS: "90"} || {SECURITYCLASS: "93"});
```

but the result contains object with SECURITYCLASS value 90 only.
i.e

```
0: Object
SECURITYCLASS: 90
USERID: "ASISH90" 

1: Object
SECURITYCLASS: 90
USERID: "VANDERSONIR"

2: Object
SECURITYCLASS: 90
USERID: "BISWA90"
```

I know its possible to filter by SECURITYCLASS: "90" and SECURITYCLASS: "93" ; merge them to get the final result.

but Is it possible by using  `$filter` only once?

Is it possible to filter with multiple constraints ?

Comment: YES it is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18792135/6449750

Comment: may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20849804/filter-by-multiple-columns-with-ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a custom `filter`. By evaluating multiple conditions in one `filter` it will gain 'performance'.

```
$scope.filterData = function (item) {
    return (item.SECURITYCLASS === 90 || item.SECURITYCLASS === 93);
}
```

On your view :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:filterData">
    {{::item}}
</div>
```

See [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/aDx3SfXaTqEqrlMxIzgd)