# Angular ng-click does not work in Bootstrap drowdown menu

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have some filters based on the Bootstrap 3 dropdown menu, but for some odd reason they do not work in the actual dropdown menu, but if i copy-paste it and place it outside it works fine.

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-controller="ExerciseCtrl" >
    <div class="btn-group" ng-class="{open: open}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" ng-click="open=!open">Equipment <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li ng-repeat="equipment in equipments">
                <a href ng-click="myFilter = {equipment:'{%verbatim%}{{equipment.name}}{%endverbatim%}'}">{%verbatim%}{{equipment.name}}{%endverbatim%}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>    

    <table class="table table-hover" >
        <tr><td><strong>Name</strong></td><td><strong>Main muscle</strong></td><td><strong>Equipment</strong></td></tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="exercise in exercises | filter:myFilter | orderBy:orderProp">
            {%verbatim%}<td>{{exercise.name}}</td><td>{{exercise.main_muscle.name}}</td><td>{{exercise.equipment.name}}</td>{%endverbatim%}
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

One menu item looks like following:

```
<li ng-repeat="equipment in equipments" class="ng-scope">
     <a href="" ng-click="myFilter = {equipment:'Dumbbell'}" class="ng-binding">Dumbbell</a>
</li>
```

So basically if i pull out the `a`link and place it before the `table` it works, but not inside the actual dropdown menu.

Comment: Can you confirm that ngClick works without anything funny, maybe just calling a function on your controller?

Comment: If i copy `<a href="" ng-click="myFilter = {equipment:'Dumbbell'}" class="ng-binding">Dumbbell</a>` and add it below the `table` it works. Can i use this to confirm its functionality?

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to determine if ngClick is never called, i.e. something is stopping click event propagation inside the dropdown, or something else is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myFilter` is being set on a [child scope created by](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes) `ng-repeat`, and is not visible to your table.  Try using an object property, such as `my.filter`, instead.

```
$scope.my = {
  filter: ''
}
```

html:

```
<li ng-repeat="equipment in equipments">
  <a href ng-click="my.filter = equipment.name">...</a>
</li>
...
<tr ng-repeat="exercise in exercises | filter:{ name: my.filter} ...
```

Here is a demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ogfe7MxRRIovTG9bQCWN?p=preview

Comment: I added the object property to my controller, changed `myFilter` to `my.filter`. When i click the buttons in the navbar it just clears the result, so basically the `ng-click` fires now, but the result is empty.

Comment: The other problem you'll have is that the `{{equipment.name}}` won't be interpolated inside the click expression.  You should just set the filter to equipment.  See my updated plunkr.

Comment: Updated plunk again, changing items to objects more like your situation.

Comment: That did the trick, so if i have multiple filters i wish to combine, these can just be added to the filter?

Comment: Check out this post for more info about filtering http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field.  Also see http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter for details about specifying multiple properties to filter by, in the object form of the expression parameter.