# AngularJs ng-click not working on Bootstrap dropdown

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 CSS **only without bootstrap js or jQuery** with AngularJs framework, But I have a very basic usage issue which is `ng-click`not get fired on bootstrap `dropdown`

HTML

```
<div class="fc-couponThumbnail">

<i class="icon-ok" ng-if="coupon.couponMainImage=='couponThmub1'"></i>
<div class="dropdown">
    <button  type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" >
        <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu"  >
        <li ><a ng-click="coupon.couponMainImage='couponThmub1';">set main image</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="coupon.couponThmub1=''">delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

as I am not using bootstrap js so I made this directive to get dropdown toggled

```
angular.module('FansCoupon').directive('dropdownToggle', function () {
return{
    restrict:'C',
    link:function(scope,ele,attrs){

        ele.on('click', function () {
                ele.parent().toggleClass('open')

        })
        ele.on('blur', function () {
            ele.parent().removeClass('open')
        })
    }
}
})
```

**Edit I**

When I instantiate `.dropdown` with `open` class the `ng-click` work properly!

**Edit II**

calling a function instead of do javascript directly in `ng-click` didn't worked too.

Comment: Could you try and call a method instead? E.g. 'showHideCoupon()' or something, not convinced about doing assignment in ng-click directly is a good idea

Comment: tried this but it still doesn't working :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093291/angular-ng-click-does-not-work-in-bootstrap-drowdown-menu

Comment: @fljs Thanks for your comment, the link you provided is not related to my issue the issue of this link is about using filters and ng-repaet in bootstrap dropdown which I am not using at all plus I am not working with jQuery or bootstrap js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the solution for my issue was to use Angular UI Bootstrap which handling all bootstrap components as angular Js directives so I used `uib-dropdown`,`uib-dropdown-toggle` and `uib-dropdown-menu`

and my code now looks like :

```
<div class="dropdown" uib-dropdown >
<button  type="button" uib-dropdown-toggle class="dropdown-toggle" >

    <span class="caret"></span>
</button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu >
    <li ><a ng-click="coupon.couponMainImage=coupon.couponThmub4;">set main image</a></li>
    <li><a ng-click="coupon.couponThmub4=''">delete</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You could try escaping the quotes if you want, that might also make the first one work: `ng-click="coupon.couponThumb4=\"\""`. Also, is it `Thumb` or `Thmub`?

Comment: @cst1992 thanks for your reply! .. my issue is the ng-click not fired even if I called a function instead of write any expressions