# not show specific resource in select drop down in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I get my data from the server and show it in a select drop down.

```
<select ng-model="selectedProject" ng-options="proj as proj.Name for proj in projects" ng-change="onSelectChange()"></select>
```

Is there a way to not show a specific `proj`?  For example,

```
if (proj.Id != currentProject.Id)
```

The drop down basically shows all the projects, and I want to show all the projects except the current one.  Is this possible with the `<select>`?  Or do I need to use ng-repeat?

Comment: why don't you implement a filter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Angular.js ng-repeat :filter by single field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Comment: below answer will fetch(using filter) all current proj.Id==currentProject.Id... and not proj.Id!=currentProject.Id...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with the help of your guys comments and answers, I did this:

```
options = "proj as proj.Name for proj in projects | filter:selectItems"

$scope.selectItems = function (item) {
   return item.Id != $scope.currentProject.Id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use filters

```
<select ng-model="selectedProject" 
        ng-options="proj as proj.Name for proj in projects | filter:{ Id : currentProject.Id }" 
        ng-change="onSelectChange()"></select>
```