# Angular binding updates when service provides unfiltered array but doesn't when using Underscore

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js, angular-services

I have an angular service which contains two function to return an array of objects. The first returns the entire array, and the second a filtered array based on an ID. When I use the first function returning all the objects, data-binding works automatically and my front end updates as soon as I push a new object to the array. However when I use the function that returns a filtered list using underscore, my frontend doesn't update automatically.

I've done some research and the only thing similar to this that I have seen is in relation to async requests and using promises, but I'm not sure if this is appropriate in this case as I'm only using in service objects currently.

**Service**

```
angular.module('RankingsApp')
.service('results', function() {    
    var uid = 2;
    var results = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "fencer":1,
        "competition":1,
        "placing":1,
        "points":50
    }
    ];

    this.getResults = function()
    {
        return results;
    }

    this.getResultsForCompetition = function (_id) 
    {
        var resultsForCompetition = _.filter(results, function(x){ return x.competition == _id});

        return resultsForCompetition;
    };

    this.insertResult = function (result) {
        result.id = uid++;
        results.push(result);
    };



});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('RankingsApp')
.controller('CompetitionCtrl', function ($scope, competitions,fencers,results, $routeParams) {

    $scope.getResults = function()
    {
        return results.getResultsForCompetition($routeParams.competitionID);
    }

    $scope.competition = competitions.getCompetition($routeParams.competitionID);
    $scope.fencers = fencers.getFencers();  
    $scope.compResults = results.getResultsForCompetition($routeParams.competitionID);



    function getNextPlacing()
    {
        return $scope.compResults.length + 1;
    }

    $scope.getFencerFromResult = function(result)
    {
        return fencers.getFencer(result.fencer);        
    }

    $scope.getCompFromResult = function(result)
    {
        return competitions.getCompetition(result.competition);     
    }



    $scope.addNewResult = function(fencer)
    {
        var result = { "fencer": fencer.id,  "competition":$routeParams.competitionID,  "placing": getNextPlacing(), "points":50 };
        results.insertResult(result);       
        $scope.selectedFencer = null;

    }       
});
```

**View**

```
<table style="width: 100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Placeing</th>
                            <th>Fencer</th>
                            <th>Comp</th>                           
                            <th>Points</th>                         
                            <th>Edit</th>                           
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat='result in compResults'>
                            <td>{{result.placing}}</td>
                            <td>{{getFencerFromResult(result).firstname}} {{getFencerFromResult(result).lastname}}</td>
                            <td>{{getCompFromResult(result).shortName}}</td>
                            <td>{{result.points}}</td>                                              
                            <td><a>Edit</a></td>                            
                        </tr>                       
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because your method (with `_.filter()`) returns **another** array than what your view in the frontend was bind to (as binding is done by reference in case of an `Array` or an `Object`).

To solve this, you may place filtering logic in views and use `ng-repeat`.

If it's not an option, you should directly modify the `results` variable in the `service` by using `pop()`/`push()` methods.

Update:

```
<tr ng-repeat='result in compResults'>
```

should be

```
<tr ng-repeat='result in compResults | filter{ competition: _id }'>
```

where

`$scope.compResults = results.getResults();`

and

```
$scope._id = $routeParams.competitionID;
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/angular-js-ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Comment: I've updated my post with the view, when you say filter in the view, could you explain what you mean? Do you mean use the ng-repeat to make the call to the service?

Comment: Would it not be wasteful to return all the results? For example what if there was 1000+ or 2000+ in the array down the line?

Comment: Well, sure, if there was 10 000 elements that would need to be filtered in the array, there would be a need for an optimization. But it would be another question. If your service has a need for such optimization, the angularjs bindings are the first thing you would need to get rid of and start to render things directly (with pagination).

Comment: And you don't return all results, you return a pointer to the array, not the whole structure

Answer (score 0):

Using the advice posted by @Mironor I was able to come up with the following solution which solves my issue. By changing the ng-repeat to call the function directly the list updates itself when I push a new value to the service.

**View**

```
<tr ng-repeat='result in getResultsForCompetition(competitionID)'>
```

Comment: Bare in mind that during digest cycle angularJs will re-evaluate getResultsForCompetition(competitionID) to render new or delete removed models. I doubt that this is faster than the filter included in ng-repeat.