# List in Ionic with conditions

Tags: angularjs, list, ionic-framework, conditional-statements

I have this html:

```
<ion-content>
<div class="bar bar-header bar-light">
  <h1 class="title">{{ 'SchoolHours' | translate}}</h1>
</div>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item ng-repeat="day in days">
      {{day}}
      <ion-list>
          <ion-item ng-repeat="subject in list_subjects">
              <h2>{{subject.theme.name}}</h2>
              <h3>{{subject.hour_ini}} - {{subject.hour_finish}}</h3>
              <h3>{{ 'Teacher' | translate }} : {{subject.teacher.name}} - {{subject.teacher.mail}}</h3>
          </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**days** array is like this: ["Monday", "Tuesday",..]
**list_subjects** array  has got objects. These objects have got an attribute called weekday.

I would like in the second list of HTML, it lists only objects that matches with current day in **days** array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution#1**

You need to make your own filter for this purpose, which will be like this

```
.filter("filterByDays", function(filterFilter){
  return function (subjects, day) {
    return filterFilter(subjects,{weekday:day})
  };
});
```

And use it like this

```
<ion-item ng-repeat="subject in subjects|filterByDays:day">
```

Demo with your code : http://play.ionic.io/app/a2238d1002a1 
Documenation on how to write own filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09

**Solution#2**

Well this is the most simpler one, you should use groupBy filter provided by https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter , in this case you will not have to use `days` array to make group of subjects by days. This filter will do all grouping by using `weekday` property of subject. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026558/angular-js-ng-repeat-division/32026961#32026961) on how to use that.
Demo with your code: http://play.ionic.io/app/9f069e28c42a 
 **NOTE:**
Do not use `ng-if` for your case, using filters is best and optimized solution for these kind of situdations.