# Angular JS and Ionic - Search filter not working for local storage item from rest api

Tags: javascript, angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework

I have a Angular/Ionic application.

I have a data coming into a list item from a Wordpress rest api, problem is my search filter does not work. my code is:

```
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags track by $index | filter: search'>
    <label class="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.city[$index]">
    </label>
    <p ng-bind-html="tag.title"></p>
</li>
```

SEARCH:

```
<div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
        <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    </label>
    <button class="button ion-close-circled input-button button-small" ng-click="search = ''">Clear search</button>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think the ***filter: search*** in ng-repeat does not work that way.

Comment: Then how do they work?

Comment: Maybe you can read about this, [Filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter). Sorry, I can't make an example for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<li class="item item-checkbox" ng-repeat='tag in item.tags | filter: searchfilter'>
    <label class="checkbox">
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="option.city[$index]">
    </label>
    <p ng-bind-html="tag.title"></p>
</li>
```

***SEARCH:***

```
<div class="item item-input-inset">
    <label class="item-input-wrapper">
       <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"></i>
       <input type="text" placeholder="Search" ng-model="search">
    </label>
    <button class="button ion-close-circled input-button button-small" ng-click="searchfilter = search">Clear search</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat :filter by single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field). Hope this helps.

> See the example on the [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter) page.  Use an object, and set the color in the color property:

> ```
> Search by color: <input type="text" ng-model="search.color">
> <div ng-repeat="product in products | filter:search">
> ```