# ng-repeat filter returns indexOf value instead of equality

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I have list of countries and I want to filter by id as told in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14733352/492258)
This is [my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18621/):

```
  <div ng-repeat="c in countries | filter:{id: 1}">
     {{c}}
  </div>
```

Instead of id equals 1

```
 {"id":1,"name":"AUSTRIA"}
```

it list all countries id including `1`:

```
{"id":1,"name":"AUSTRIA"}
{"id":10,"name":"GREECE"}
{"id":11,"name":"HUNGARY"}
{"id":12,"name":"IRELAND"}
{"id":13,"name":"ITALY"}
{"id":14,"name":"LATVIA"}
{"id":15,"name":"LITHUANIA"}
{"id":16,"name":"MALTA"}
{"id":17,"name":"NETHERLANDS"}
{"id":18,"name":"POLAND"}
{"id":19,"name":"PORTUGAL"}
{"id":21,"name":"SLOVAKIA"}
{"id":31,"name":"NORWAY"}
```

What is wrong with my code

Comment: Do you have to use angular 1.0.3.  In 1.2.1  (or possibly earlier), you can just use the `strict` comparison like so `<div ng-repeat="c in countries | filter:{id: 1}:true">`. See [docs](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/docs/api/ng/filter/filter). Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hoetm89h/)

Comment: No it is an obligation, but I wonder why this does not filter properly?

Comment: From their [old docs]() it says it will match by checking that it "contains" the value rather than exact matching so it was by design I'd say. I'm guessing the reason behind it is say you're creating a dynamic filter for the user and they type "P", you'd expect "Poland" and "Portugal" to show up in the list instead of nothing.

Answer (score 1):

He is a working version : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/moncef_hbey/U3pVM/18623/)

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="c in countries | filter:{id: 1} : true">
         {{c}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

So, two things to make it works :

1. Include more recent angular version (I'm using 1.2.1 here).
2. Change the comparator in the filter to true (by default : false => substring match).