# ng-repeat filter to iterate only over elements with certain property value

Tags: angularjs, filter, properties, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to ng-repeat through an array, but `filter` the results so that only the elements that match a certain property value will be displayed. Is this possible, and how?

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do (and obviously failing):

### HTML (View)

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: person.gender == 'male'"></li>
</ul>

<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: person.gender == 'female'"></li>
</ul>
```

### JS (Controller)

```
$scope.people = [

  {name: "John", gender: "male"},

  {name: "Sue", gender: "female"},

  {name: "Maria", gender: "female"},

  {name: "Bob", gender: "male"},

]
```

So the first list should just print the male names, and the second female, based on the property values.

Is this possible using ng-repeat's filter? Or if not is there another way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what you did seems precise.. you can filter by using filter ... what else do you need  ?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/Aj4F8aVeHks4WvkK10xa?p=preview  you got it in plunker

Comment: Thanks - that's what I was after!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat :filter by single field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.
if put :true after filter then filtering do exactly on match value.

```js
function Main($scope) {
    $scope.people = [

  {name: "John", gender: "male"},

  {name: "Sue", gender: "female"},

  {name: "Maria", gender: "female"},

  {name: "Bob", gender: "male"}

];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="Main">
      <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="person in people | filter: { gender: 'male' }:true">
   {{person.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

    </div>
</div>
```