# Angular filter related data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am still fairly new to angular so I was wondering how to best do something like this:

- I have a json file that returns a variety of items of type 'course' and type 'tutorial'. Tutorials are related to courses with a field

  `data = [
    { title: foo1, type: course, id:1},
    { title: foo2, type: course, id:2},
    { title: foo3, type: course, id:3},
    { title: t1, type: tutorial, id:4, related_course:2},
    { title: t2, type: tutorial, id:5, related_course:2},
    { title: t3, type: tutorial, id:6, related_course:3},
    ...`

In my controller I have functions bound to `$scope` to allow me to filter by type.

Now in my template

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data | filter:isCourse">
... display course data
   <div ng-repeat="item in data | filter.isTutorial">
   ... display tutorial data
```

I would like to find a way to make sure the tutorials displayed match the id of the currently displayed course.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!
- V

Comment: may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35830338/ng-repeat-filter-to-iterate-only-over-elements-with-certain-property-value/35830473#35830473

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have then be specific with `filters`, but do make sure that JSON should be in correct format, as I can see most of the values are not there wrap in `"`(double quotes)

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="course in data | filter: {type: 'course'}">
... display course data
   <div ng-repeat="tut in data | filter: { related_course: course.id }">
   ... display tutorial data
```

[**Working Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/dos43ny3/)(Thanks @AWolf)

Comment: Good answer. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/dos43ny3/) to show how the code is working.

Comment: @AWolf thanks for efforts man.. I did update a answer with your fiddle. :-)

Comment: Thanks @PankajParkar @AWolf - that works! One last thing is is there a simple way to insert a header before the second `ng-repeat` if tutorials are found... ?