# How to filter ng-repeat in Angular by certain property value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter, angular-filters

I'm trying to display an array of objects with ng-repeat but only the ones with the property value of

**"category": "Problems"**

This is my view

```
<div class="small-6 large-6 columns" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { category: Problems }">
  <span><a href="#/posts/{{getSlug(post.title)}}"><img src='img/posts/{{post.img}}.jpg' /></a></span>
  <div class="category"><a href="#">{{post.category}}</a></div>
  <a class="title" href="#/posts/{{getSlug(post.title)}}">{{post.title}}</a>
  <div class="meta"><span class="date">{{post.date | date:'dd MMMM yyyy'}}</span></div>
</div>
```

And controller if needed

```
.controller('PostListController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $http.get('data/posts.json').success(function(response){
      $scope.posts = response;
      $scope.getSlug = function(text){
          return text.replace(/\W+/g, '-');
        };
    });
}])
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat :filter by single field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error, add single quotes around `Problems` like:

```
<div class="small-6 large-6 columns" ng-repeat="post in posts | filter: { category: 'Problems'}">
```

Angular silently determines `Problems` (as a variable) as `undefined` instead of throwing a `ReferenceError`.