# Angularjs:How to remove dynamical table row, but no remove from array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This down is small from my html code.The code add/remove dynamical row.

```
 <tr class="clone" ng-repeat="dataItem in dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items track by $index">
                <td class="number">{{$index + 1}}</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="codeto{{$index}}"  size="11" ng-model="dataItem.item.code" ng-keyup="getCodeItem($index)" class="tagsItem">
                <td><input type="hidden" id="hidden{{$index + 1}}"   ng-model="dataItem.item.itemID" >
                    <input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.item.itemName"  id="item{{$index}}"  class="tagsItem" ng-keyup="getItemInvoice($index)"  name="itemName" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.item.solid" size="11" id="solid{{$index + 1}}"   ng-disabled="invoice.itemName.$error.required"    required></td>
                <td><input type="text"  ng-model="dataItem.quantity" id="quantity{{$index+1}}" ng-keyup="totals($index+1)" size="10"  ng-disabled="invoice.itemName.$error.required" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.price"    ng-keyup="totals($index+1)" value="111" id="price{{$index + 1}}"  ng-disabled="invoice.itemName.$error.required" required></td>
    <td><input type="text" ng-model="dataItem.discount"  id="discount{{$index+1}}" ng-keyup="totals($index+1)" size="11" ng-disabled="invoice.itemName.$error.required" required></td>
                <td>{{dataItem.quantity * dataItem.price * (1 - dataItem.discount / 100) | number:2}}</td>
                <td><a class="btn btn-default" ng-click="removeItem ($index)">-</a></td>

            </tr>
```

This is  my  funciton for remove dynamical row.When click on "removeItem" button removen row, but and removen element from array on my all items.
I want to remove dynamicla row, but do not delete element from my array with all items.

```
$scope.removeItem = function (index)
{
console.log($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items);

$scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items.splice (index, 1);

console.log($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items);
$scope.total ($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items);
};
```

Comment: you can use ng-show directive for this.

Comment: You can just put css display = none to the row or how @SSH said  just ng-show or ng-hide

Comment: Ng-show How will you know which row to delete, i have ng-repeat row over from one .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `ngIf` directive to the row:

```
 <tr class="clone" ng-repeat="dataItem in dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items track by $index" ng-if="!dataItem.deleted">
```

And you can pass the object to the `removeItem` function in the controller:

```
ng-click="removeItem (dataItem)" <!-- Instead of '$index' -->
```

And change the controller function:

```
$scope.removeItem = function (dataItem) {
    console.log($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items);
    dataItem.deleted = true;
    var total = $scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items.filter(function(item) { return typeof(item.deleted) === 'undefined' || !item.deleted; });  // get only the undeleted items

    $scope.total (total);
};
```

Comment: Hi your script is Perfect  work, but have anorther problem: After i click on removeItem (), my  result in html code have problem.After  Ng-repeat my result are: 1 some text,2 some text ,3 some text.After click on  function i deleted  result (2) i see: 1 some text, 3 some text.

Comment: @СтилиянГеоргиев Hey, in that case, you can remove the `ngIf` and add to the `ngRepeat` a filter that will show only the un-deleted items: `ng-repeat="....... | filter: { 'deleted': '!true'}` **IMPORTANT!!! -** You MUST **NOT** trust `$index` as a reference to an item inside `dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items` because it's actually the index of the filtered list. You need to convert functions like `ng-keyup="getItemInvoice($index)"` to `ng-keyup="getItemInvoice(dataItem)"` to avoid unexpected behaviours

Comment: Hey this work in half.I  click on  function ( removeItem  ), but no deleted table row in  my  html.

Comment: You mean that after you click on the remove button, you can still see the row in the view?

Comment: Yes!Result after ne-repeat are 4 rows, i click on  remove button  and i see 4-rows again, all everything else works.

Comment: $scope.removeItem = function (dataItem) {
 console.log ($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items);
 dataItem.deleted = 1;
 var dataItems = $scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items.filter (function (
  item) {
     return !item.deleted;
 });  // get only the undeleted items
 console.log ($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items);

 $scope.total ($scope.dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items);
    };

Comment: And does your `ngRepeat` is `ng-repeat="dataItem in dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items track by $index | filter: { 'deleted': '!true'}"`? You may also try to remove ` track by $index` if it doesn't work (Not sure if it will work, but worth a try)

Comment: Yes,<tr class="clone" ng-repeat="dataItem in dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items track by $index | filter: { 'deleted': '!true'}">I  remove this track by $index, no  work again

Comment: Oh, you put `dataItem.deleted = 1;` in your controller, so try replace `filter: { 'deleted': '!true'}` with `filter: { 'deleted': '!1'}` or change your controller from `dataItem.deleted = 1;` to `dataItem.deleted = true;`

Comment: I am very sorry for the stupid mistake, even if I did not see that there really is a difference! Many, many thanks- Now all work perfect !

Comment: That's totally fine. Glad to help out!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is a soft delete in angularjs.

you can achieve this by using a Filter on your ng-repeat:

```
<tr class="clone" ng-repeat="dataItem in dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items track by $index | filter: { 'isDeleted': 'false'}">...</tr>
```

By setting the isDeleted property of dataItem (any rows of dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items) to true, the filter will remove all of the rows that contain the property isDeleted : true.

Doing this will have the correct display behaviour while keeping the rows that are removed from display.

reference for [ng-repeat filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Comment: Beware of using `$index` and `filter` - It will get the index of the filtered collection, and not the original index of the item

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-if` for better performance. Not a issue of extra watcher.

```
<tr class="clone" ng-repeat="dataItem in dataInvoce.Invoicetoitem.items track by $index" ng-if="dataItem.isDeleted">
```

inside controller `$scope.removeItem` method set `dataItem.isDeleted = true;` also pass `dataItem` rather than `$index`