# How do i accurately implement a filter for Angular application

Tags: angularjs

I'm facing a bit of an issue with my filters in Angular. Can i request you to follow the link below:
https://ngmasters.firebaseapp.com/#/masters

Now, if i were to select 'Hitchens' from the 'Select a Master' dropdown, i have information being displayed for Hitchens and The Others. I'm not quite sure of the reason of this result. This problem does not seem to present itself when i have any other Master selected.

So, my query is how do i accurately implement a filter in this case so that only the information is accurately narrowed down?

The foll is the code:

```
<md-input-container>
        <label>Enter Search Term</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="classifiedsFilter">
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <label>Select a Master</label>
        <md-select ng-model="name">
            <md-option ng-repeat="name in names | orderBy: 'toString()'" value="{{ name }}">  
                {{ name }} 
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
    </md-input-container>

    <md-input-container>
        <md-button class="md-warn" ng-click="classifiedsFilter = ''; name = ''">Clear</md-button>
    </md-input-container>
```

The foll is the code on my md-card:

```
<md-card ng-repeat="classified in classifieds | filter: classifiedsFilter | 
filter: name" flex-xs="100" flex-gt-sm="70">
```

Any help wld be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In given link, it seems that The Others's contains word Hitchens so its filtering that result too. To filter by specific property of `classified`  object you may find this link useful [ng-repeat :filter by single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)