# AngularJS display data of index that has matching value

Tags: html, angularjs

I am working on a dashboard and am trying to display a certain piece of data. In my scope I have a project which consists of a couple fields and an array of users. The users consist of the following fields:

- user_id
- user_name
- user_email
- role

I want to display the user_name of the role which matches a certain value.  Is there a way to do this within my html file or is it recommended to do this in my controller?

My table code looks as follows:

```
<tbody md-body>
        <tr md-row md-select="project" md-select-id="name" md-auto-select
            ng-repeat="project in projects.data | orderBy : myOrder">
            <td md-cell ng-click="getProject()">{{project.title}}</td>
            <td md-cell><i class="material-icons" style="color: green">radio_button_checked</i></td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.phase}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.budget_indication}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.users}}</td> <!-- Display user with specific role -->
            <td md-cell>{{project.start_date | date:dd/MM/yyyy}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try adding filter for role `|filter:role`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `project.data` contains objects which has the role property (`project.role`) then you could use angular filter to filter against that property like this

```
Search by role: <input type="text" ng-model="roleSearch">

<tbody md-body>
        <tr md-row md-select="project" md-select-id="name" md-auto-select
            ng-repeat="project in projects.data | filter:{ role: roleSearch }| orderBy : myOrder">
            <td md-cell ng-click="getProject()">{{project.title}}</td>
            <td md-cell><i class="material-icons" style="color: green">radio_button_checked</i></td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.phase}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.budget_indication}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.users}}</td> <!-- Display user with specific role -->
            <td md-cell>{{project.start_date | date:dd/MM/yyyy}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Read more about filters [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

More examples in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field) SO question

**Update**

To set the default filter value, you could set the roleSearch in the controller:

```
$scope.roleSearch = 'Admin';
```

To filter by the users.role add this filter

```
filter:{ users.role: roleSearch }
```

Comment: This seems like a good way of doing it. However I would like to make it happen automatically when the page is loaded. So I could add a default roleSearch value. My second issue is that role is not directly in the scope of project, it can be found in project.users[index] instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody md-body>
        <tr md-row md-select="project" md-select-id="name" md-auto-select
            ng-repeat="project in projects.data | orderBy : myOrder"  ng-if="project.users === 'role'">
            <td md-cell ng-click="getProject()">{{project.title}}</td>
            <td md-cell><i class="material-icons" style="color: green">radio_button_checked</i></td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.phase}}</td>
            <td md-cell>{{project.budget_indication}}</td>
            <td md-cell>  {{project.users}} </td> <!-- Display user with specific role -->
            <td md-cell>{{project.start_date | date:dd/MM/yyyy}}</td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Assuming **role** is specific role

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter:role`

**`<div>{{x.users | filter: role= "User"}}</div>`**

Here is an example I have taken to get your solution,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
 
Role: {{ role ? role : 'All Data'}}    <br><br>

<div ng-repeat="x in projects">
  <div>{{x.users | filter: role= role}}</div>
  
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.projects = [{
  users:  [
    {
      "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
      "Country" : "Germany",
      "Role": "User"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
      "Country" : "Sweden",
      "Role": "Admin"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
      "Country" : "Mexico",
      "Role": "User"
    },
    {
      "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
      "Country" : "Austria",
      "Role": "Admin"
    }
  ]
  }]
  
  $scope.role = "User"
  
  });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Just change the role to "Admin" and check the filter**

[Here is the DEMO link which contain ADMIN role](https://plnkr.co/edit/Rif647z4mqZeuomEkZuL?p=preview)