# Filter (ngRepeat) in a table not working on all columns

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to filter my table generated with a `ng-repeat`.

```html
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in contact.listeContacts | filter:contact.searchText track by $index">
                <td>
                    <b>{{x.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t}}</b>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{contact.listeContacts[$index].gd$name.gd$familyName.$t}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{contact.listeContacts[$index].gd$name.gd$givenName.$t}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{contact.listeContacts[$index].gd$email[0].address}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{contact.listeContacts[$index].gd$phoneNumber[0].$t}}</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>{{contact.listeContacts[$index].gd$organization[0].gd$orgTitle.$t}}{{contact.listeContacts[$index].gd$organization[0].gd$orgName.$t}}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

My issue is that my filter seems to be applied only on the first column.

Imagine I have these three objects to display :

```
obj1 = {
'name':'obj1',
'age':10
}

obj2 = {
    'name':'obj2',
    'age':1000
}

obj3 = {
    'name'='obj3',
    'age':100000
}
```

If my `searchText` is "obj3", the table will display something like this `obj3 / 10`

instead of `obj3 / 100000`

I don't understand why behaving like this.

**EDIT:** John Joseph, Xun Chao & tanmay helped me to resolve my first problem, check their answers.

Now, I don't understand why my search filter is not working as expected. Please see this Plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/SfaYdgVkSfhOdI5enpOd?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While all provided answers are correct, none of them has explained why this happened. When you filter with "`obj3`", it displays only one item in the `ng-repeat` but your `contact.listeContacts` array still has length say 3. So, while searching for third item's text (here `obj3`), it tries to show `contact.listeContacts[0]` because filtered array has only one element.

You have two ways to solve this:

1. As mentioned by all other answers, put `x` instead of `contact.listeContacts[$index]`
2. You can have a reference to filtered array like this:

   `<tr ng-repeat="x in mycontacts = (contact.listeContacts | filter:contact.searchText) track by $index">`

   And, instead of `contact.listeContacts[$index]` you can then use `mycontacts[$index]` which points to filtered array and not actual array

Comment: Thanks for explained to me this behavior, it was a little bit weird!
I still don't understand how filter is working. Actually, it's not working like I expect ^^

Comment: about this, when I try a search on my objects, on got this : http://imgur.com/a/8U5z5
Why "Google" search is not working, and "pix" search got a blank result in my tab ?

Comment: I can't provide you an exact Plunker, because my array of objects is generated by a Google GET request :/

Comment: Sorry for waiting time, I had to rewrite some things ^^
Here's the Plunkr, with the same "bug" searching. https://plnkr.co/edit/SfaYdgVkSfhOdI5enpOd?p=preview

Comment: @Zooly the problem with your code is you are trying to search for nested properties in a very deep object.. default filter doesn't support that.. you can maybe create a custom filter that could possibly aggregate all searches..

Comment: after some tests, is seems working on email field, but not others

Comment: I see.. But why is it working on email field ? Email is accessible from obj[$index].gd$email[0].address -> deep too

Comment: @Zooly hmm not sure how they search for deep levels.. I'd recommend putting up a new question with the plunker added and describing how you want to filter multiple deep properties in an ng-repeat.. that way a lot of other people would see the question and have possibly better ways to solve that problem now that current one is fixed

Comment: I understand. Thanks a lot for your time, I will ask it in a new ask.

Comment: @Zooly you can remove unnecessary comments from here.. also share the new question link if possible, would like to learn too :) maybe mark answer as accepted if helped

Comment: I prefer keep all comments to understand process searching.
Here's the new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43735702/how-does-work-filter-angularjs

Answer (score 1):

You are directly accessing the contact.listeContacts for the rest of the columns instead of the looped variable x. That should be the problem. Try the following, replace `contact.listeContacts[$index]` with x.

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in contact.listeContacts | filter:contact.searchText track by $index">
            <td>
                <b>{{x.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t}}</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$name.gd$familyName.$t}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$name.gd$givenName.$t}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$email[0].address}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$organization[0].gd$orgTitle.$t}}{{x.gd$organization[0].gd$orgName.$t}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Exactly... it's working now, thanks a lot !
Just a question now, the search is not fully working. I don't really know where the filter is applied. Is it applied on all properties of x ?

Comment: @Zooly That's right. If you want to filter by specific field, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field).

Comment: Thanks for this link, will check it. Could you explain me how the filter is applied without specify a field ?

Comment: @Zooly it will be applied to all object properties as you guessed.

Comment: But I got strange results after the filter. See these examples.
http://imgur.com/a/8U5z5
First, search field is empty, all my elements are displayed.
Second, I'm searching for Google, the table doesn't change.
Third, I write 'pix' for Google Pixel, and all the elements disappear.
I don't understand this behavior

Comment: @Zooly Create a function for your filter. Check out this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cSvjD6fdx7JVhovfNdxx?p=preview). It's currently set to exactly match the search term. You can modify it the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You have used contact.listeContacts[$index] instead of x...

```
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in contact.listeContacts | filter:contact.searchText track by $index">
            <td>
                <b>{{x.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t}}</b>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$name.gd$familyName.$t}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$name.gd$givenName.$t}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$email[0].address}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t}}</p>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p>{{x.gd$organization[0].gd$orgTitle.$t}}{{x.gd$organization[0].gd$orgName.$t}}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Exactly... it's working now, thanks a lot !
Just a question now, the search is not fully working. I don't really know where the filter is applied. Is it applied on all properties of x ?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the `$index` you use for accessing your items. Whenever your list in `ng-repeat` is filtered, the `index` property is looping on your *filtered* list.

You just have to use your local variable, named `x` in your case.

See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JNJRVK) for a live example:

```
<td>{{contact.name}}</td>
<td>{{contacts[$index].name}}</td> <!-- may not be the same -->
```

Comment: This is not working. I don't have contacts array in my project. 
contact is my ControllerAs, not an object here

Comment: I've not followed your application architecture to the letter, it was merely an example _showing_ the said behavior. It's up to you to adapt this to your code.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood your answer :/ Indeed, it fits  a lil bit with my issue

Comment: Don't worry, no offense taken.