# How does filter work in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a table generated with `ng-repeat` (from an objects' array).

I would like to filter it with a search text field.

Objects contained in my array has got deep properties.

I don't know why and how, but the filter is only working on email field, which is as deep as other properties.

I'm using this search form :

```
<input type="text" name="search" ng-model="searchText" />
...
<tr ng-repeat="x in obj | filter:searchText track by $index">
  ...
</tr>
```

[**plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/SfaYdgVkSfhOdI5enpOd)

**EDIT :**

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43736341/4781975) helps me to understand why it's not working.
Someone knows how I can bypass the $ verification in filter ?

I'm using *$* because I'm following the Google Contact API format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`email` works because nested property `address` doesn't contain any `$` char.

Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to bypass this behavior, however you can make your own filter and use it in `ng-repeat`.

This is simple example that should work for you:

**JS**

```
app.filter('customFilter', function() {
  return function(items, keyword) {
    if (!keyword || keyword.length === 0) return items;

    return items.filter(function(item){
      var phrase = keyword.$.toLowerCase();
      return item.gd$name.gd$fullName.$t.toLowerCase().includes(phrase) || 
        item.gd$name.gd$familyName.$t.toLowerCase().includes(phrase) || 
        item.gd$name.gd$givenName.$t.toLowerCase().includes(phrase) ||
        item.gd$email[0].address.toLowerCase().includes(phrase) ||
        item.gd$phoneNumber[0].$t.toLowerCase().includes(phrase) ||
        (!!item.gd$organization[0].gd$orgTitle && item.gd$organization[0].gd$orgTitle.$t.toLowerCase().includes(phrase)) ||
        (!!item.gd$organization[0].gd$orgName && item.gd$organization[0].gd$orgName.$t.toLowerCase().includes(phrase));
    });
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in obj | customFilter:searchText">
```

Of course, you will have to add more checks for possible `null` values. I've just wanted to make it work on the data you've provided.

Hope, you'll find it useful.

Here's [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/8M7ajpJELP9Mf4tw3XxG?p=info)

Answer (score 5):

You can check the source code of ngFilter [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L235)
It is set to ignore keys starting with $ as it's a prefix used by AngularJS for public ($) and private ($$) properties.

Comment: Ow.. Thanks a lot, this is the explanation I expected! Do you know how I can bypass it ? And why am I able to get `gd$email` ?

Comment: @Zooly Create a function for your filter. Check out [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/cSvjD6fdx7JVhovfNdxx?p=preview). It's currently set to exactly match the search term. You can modify it the way you want to perform a search or deep search. There are no other ways as this is by design.

Comment: I think you forgot the plnkr link

Comment: @Zooly did you check the plunker?

Comment: Are you talking about this one ? https://plnkr.co/edit/cSvjD6fdx7JVhovfNdxx?p=preview

Comment: Nothing ^^ I though you were talking about a new plunkr! I will check, but not sure to understand how it works

Comment: Indeed, your plunkr is not working. I don't have any display in my table :/

Comment: It is set to match the `item.title.$t` the field as it is. So searching for the complete text will only give you a result. Did you try searching for 'Google Pixel' ? Now you need to modify it the way you want. Eg Initially if the search text is empty if you need to display the whole table add a condition in the function like `if(!$scope.searchText) { return true }`

Comment: Sorry, I come a little bit late! Indeed, I didn't understand your search method ^^ But it works well ! I will adapt it to my project. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 3):

`$` is a prefix used by Angular internal properties. For technical reasons, Angular prevents you to use it. Here is a workaround to deal with `$` properties names without changing your JSON object:

You can iterate in ng-repeat over `Object.keys($scope.object)` instead `$scope.object`.

#### [Demo on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/wrafju76/)

Answer (score 2):

Since it is clear that we can change neither third party API nor AngularJS library code, **we could go for modifying the object keys to not have `$` in the beginning**. But, since the data has so many of them at multiple level, let's do it **recursively**! :)

Here's how. I would remap each object in `$scope.obj` array to call a function:

```
$scope.obj = $scope.obj.map(function(cur) {
  return renameKey(cur)
})
```

Now, inside `renameKey`, it would check whether it's an `Array` or `Object` using helper functions and call itself recursively while replacing the keys prepending `x` for the strings starting with `$`

```
function renameKey(cur) {
  if(isArray(cur)) {
    cur.forEach(function(obj) {
      obj = renameKey(obj)
    })
  } else if (isObject(cur)) {
    for (let key in cur) {
      if(key.charAt(0) === '$') {
        cur['x'+key] = cur[key];
        delete cur[key];
      }
      cur[key] = renameKey(cur[key])
    }
  } 
  return cur
}

function isObject(obj) {
   return obj && (typeof obj === "object");
}

function isArray(obj) { 
  return isObject(obj) && (obj instanceof Array);
}
```

Looks little tedius but it does work! Now, all we need to do is have `x$t` instead of `$t` in the HTML, and boom!

[**working plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/0w90285fYoi8Lohu9bT4?p=preview)

Comment: Wow, works very well, thanks a lot tanmay for helping me on my two questions!

Comment: @Zooly np, glad that helped.. I had fun writing this! :)

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment because my reputation is less than 50 but as far as i can tell it's any property that has a $ in it's name is not used in the filter.. I tried changing the property names and this fixed the issue. Realise you may or may not have control over this.

Comment: Thanks for helping! Could you link me something about filter that tells $ is ignored in filter ? I can't find anything about it... And I can't change my property names, my app won't be maintainable after this

Answer (score -1):

Suppose your obj is as below:

```
$scope.obj=[{firstName:'Jeet',lastName:'kumar'},{firstName:'test1',lastName:'dev'},{firstName:'test2',lastName:'other'}];
```

Search input box

```
<input type="text" name="search" ng-model="searchText" />
```

Datatable filter by index 'firstName'

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in obj | filter:{firstName:searchText}">
 <td>{{x.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{x.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Datatable filter over all index

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in obj | filter:searchText">
 <td>{{x.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{x.lastName}}</td>
</tr>
```

Desc:

```
filter:{name:searchText}
filter on the basis of 'firstName' index from your $socpe.obj array
```

Comment: What does name in `filter:{name:sText}` stand for ? I don't see

Comment: @Zooly , i have updated my answer and i am making that filter over the firstName index , if you want to filter over all column than use as like :



ng-repeat="x in obj | filter:searchText"