# How to custom filter with dropdown in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i tried to make custom filter in angularjs with dropdown, but it not work. this is my code. i want to pass this value from this select

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="custom" >
                <option value="asd">test123</option>
```

into this filter

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in searched = (coba | filter:{{{custom}}:search}) | coba:(currentPage-1)*itemsPerPage | limitTo: viewby">
```

thank you

Comment: could explain your code a little bit? what `coba` is? Also [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Comment: coba is my module name. angular.module('coba',['ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'ui.bootstrap.pagination'])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example which may help you:

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.names = ["John", "Hannah", "Vicky"];

  $scope.coba = [{
      name: 'John'
    },
    {
      name: 'Peter'
    },
    {
      name: 'Amy'
    },
    {
      name: 'Hannah'
    },
    {
      name: 'Michael'
    },
    {
      name: 'Sandy'
    },
    {
      name: 'Betty'
    },
    {
      name: 'Richard'
    },
    {
      name: 'Susan'
    },
    {
      name: 'Vicky'
    },
    {
      name: 'Ben'
    },
    {
      name: 'William'
    },
    {
      name: 'Chuck'
    },
    {
      name: 'Viola'
    }
  ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  <select ng-model="custom" ng-options="x for x in names">
<option value="">All</option>
</select>
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in coba|filter:custom">
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <tr/>
  </table>
</div>
```