# how to add filter in angular within array

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

i have following record i want filter in ng-repeat by name  i enter but its  but not working  please help me this

```
  ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts | filter: {name: vm.chatSearch}

 "userlist": [
        {
            "_id": "59edd7c5ff809c1c4c7a43c2",
            "updatedDatetime": "2017-10-23T11:51:33.106Z",
            "createdDatetime": "2017-10-23T11:51:33.106Z",   
            "user_id": {
                "_id": "59f07d5c935f27764c8d1090",             
                "name": "james"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
        ]
```

Comment: where you want to filter on ui(`ng-repeat`) or in js(`userlist`)

Comment: ng-repeat...........

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ng-repeat :filter by single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
ng-repeat="contact in vm.contacts | filter: {user_id: {name: vm.chatSearch}}"
```

<kbd>[Demo plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dj8IWmHqV7AbQpuOqw5B?p=preview)</kbd>

---

*Example:*

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter: {user_id: {name: chatSearch}}">
    {{contact.name}}  user_id: {{contact.user_id.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

My following example may helps you

**HTML**

```html
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input ng-model="results.year">
<div ng-repeat="subject in results.subjects | filter:{grade:'A'}">
    <input ng-model="subject.title" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.results = {
    year:2013,
    subjects:[
      {title:'English',grade:'A'},
      {title:'Maths',grade:'A'},
      {title:'Science',grade:'B'},
      {title:'Geography',grade:'C'}
    ]
  };
}
```

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this,

```
<li ng-repeat="user in vm.contacts  | filter: {user_id: {name: searchterm}}"><span>{{user.user_id.name}}</span></li>
```

**DEMO**

```js
 var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
 app.controller('personController',function(){
  var vm = this;
  vm.contacts =   [
        {
            "_id": "59edd7c5ff809c1c4c7a43c2",
            "updatedDatetime": "2017-10-23T11:51:33.106Z",
            "createdDatetime": "2017-10-23T11:51:33.106Z",   
            "user_id": {
                "_id": "59f07d5c935f27764c8d1090",             
                "name": "james"
            },
            "__v": 0
        }
        ];
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app = "myapp" ng-controller = "personController as vm">
 <input ng-model="searchterm"/>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="user in vm.contacts  | filter: {user_id: {name: searchterm}}"><span>{{user.user_id.name}}</span></li>
</ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: same you posted while i was preparing the demo :)