# Filter HTTP JSON response by nested value in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, json, angular, http, filter

I want to fetch some JSON data from an external source and display it in a `<select>`- & `<option>`-Tag in my view. So far so good.

Some JSON entries have a `private: false` value. And this is where my question comes in. My destination is it, to only show the user the entries containing the `private` value set to false.

I already looked for JSON filter and found out that I could set a filter in my view in ngFor (`let appointmentType of appointmentTypes | filter: { private: false }`), but I get an error message telling me that `The pipe 'filter' could not be found`.

This is the URL I had my solution from:
[ng-repeat :filter by single field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733136/ng-repeat-filter-by-single-field)

**This is the JSON response:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 5780379,
    "name": "Appointment Type 1",
    "description": "",
    "duration": 15,
    "price": "290.00",
    "category": "REGULAR",
    "color": "#3177CA",
    "private": false
  },
  {
    "id": 5780481,
    "name": "Appointment Type 2",
    "description": "",
    "duration": 15,
    "price": "39.00",
    "category": "SERVICE",
    "color": "#D8394F",
    "private": true
  }
]
```

**This is my HTML**

```
<select type="appointmentType" [(ngModel)]="appointmentTypeId">
  <option *ngFor="let appointmentType of appointmentTypes | filter: { private: false }" [ngValue]="appointmentType.id">{{appointmentType.name}}</option>
</select>
{{appointmentTypeId}}
```

**This is my Component.TS File:**

```
import { Appointment } from './../../appointments/appointment';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { APIService } from './../../../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-booking',
  templateUrl: './booking.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./booking.component.scss']
})
export class BookingComponent implements OnInit {
  private appointmentTypes: Array<object> = [];
  appointmentTypeId: any;

  constructor(private apiService: APIService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getData();
    console.log(this.appointmentTypeId);
  }

  public getData() {
    this.apiService.getAppointmentTypes().subscribe((data: Array<object>) => {
      this.appointmentTypes = data;
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
}
```

And don't know if it's necessary, **but here's my api.service.ts:**

```
getAppointmentTypes() {
  return this.httpClient.get(`${this.API_URL}/appointment-types/`);
}
```

As I said, I managed it do display the JSON Response entries in the select option, but I only want to provide the ones where `private` is set to false.

Comment: You have been reading the AngularJS (1.x) docs, that is **not** compatible with Angular (2+): https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The filter in angularjs is different from pipe in angular . you need to implement own custom pipe to make your logic work.

your pipe should be like this,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'filter' })
export class filterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
     let result = categories.filter(t=>t.private == searchText);
     return result;
  }
}
```

**[`STACKBLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pipe-example-s6ajww?file=app%2FfilterPipe.ts)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked like a charm! :)

This wasn't my downvote. My question was also downvoted at the same time as your answer. Anyway, I upvoted and marked it as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to create your own custom pipe to do the filtering of the users list.

> Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists. Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy. There are no equivalents in Angular.

https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

This decision was made because of he inheret performance implications of allowing these types of native pipes.

I have put together a stackblitz with the solution here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqeky2

As you can see the third user who has privacy: false does not appear in the select list because it is filtered out by the custom pipe.