# Do Angular's built in services work with breezejs?

Tags: angularjs, breeze

I'm testing an angular/breeze combination and I encounter

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

and similar errors when I use angular's `$watch` and `filter:searchText` and other functions where I assume all the properties are getting checked

I'm curious of what I'm doing wrong. Or if the arrays contain too many properties or something.

Example:

```
<input type="search" ng-model="searchText" />
<div ng-repeat="station in stationsList | filter:searchText" class="view-list">
    <p>{{station.name}} </p>
</div>
```

where station is gotten from a query like `breeze.EntityQuery.from("stations")`

Edit:
At the moment I'm doing this:
[Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS (in OR relationship)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs)

works great, but more code in the controller.

Edit 2:
[How to apply a filter on multiple objects using AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13834704/angularjs-filter-on-multiple-objects)

this one too, but looping.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at a breeze entity you can see it's not just a typical javascript object but instead hides  everything under _backingStore and entityAspect. Using the AngularJS Batarang in Chrome you can more easily see the explosion of fields that I am talking about.

When you try and watch an entity the first thing Angular does is copy the the object using it's own function. This is a recursive function that dies trying to plumb the depths of entityAspect.

I don't know of anyway around this outside of the methods you already discovered unfortunately. I just manually set up a watch on each individual property that I want, foregoing object equality.

Edit: I can't comment so just to make it clearer this is what I mean by setting it manually given something like the following:

```
$scope.foo.integer1 = 4
$scope.foo.string2 = 'bar'
$scope.$watch('[foo.integer1, foo.string2]', someFunctionToHandleChange, true
```

Not sure why using a filter would be better in all cases?

Answer (score 0):

@Hawk - Even if you didn't run into entity circular references, it is rarely wise in Angular to filter (or watch) all the properties of all the objects in a list. So this is really an Angular issue, tangentially involving Breeze.

If you intend to filter on multiple properties, I recommend the filter function as described in your first link, [Filtering by Multiple Specific Model Properties in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13216115/filtering-by-multiple-specific-model-properties-in-angularjs). I personally would not watch properties individually as @Gendal proposes. Perhaps s/he has a use case in which watching individual properties is preferable to the filter; I can't think of such a case.

Yup, it is more code. Ce la vie.